# Check if window.history.go successful?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to check if a `window.history.go` command is successful in changing the `window.location` or not?

i.e. If I do a `window.history.go(-5)` when there are only 3 pages in the history stack, the browser will do nothing.

Is there a way to check if that happens and run other code? An error callback, of sorts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an immediate response, first you'll want to check `history.length` to make sure it is at least `6`, e.g. to go `-5`. Apart from that, I think the only way is to use `setTimeout` and if the script is still running, the callback will be executed.

Comment: Well, I'm actually doing `window.history.go(-(window.length-1))` so not sure how I would check `history.length` in a way that would be useful. I think I'll try the `setTimeout` method and see if that works for this purpose...

Comment: @leomancini: `if(window.length >= history.length)` then it can't possibly work.

Comment: Ack. I mistyped. I meant to say I'm doing `window.history.go(-(window.history.length-1));`

Comment: @leomancini: Are you trying to go all the way back in history? I think there's a better way.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to go back to the first page in the history stack.

Comment: @leomancini: Try `window.history.go(-(window.history.length - 1)); for(var i = 1; i < window.history.length; i++) window.history.go(-i);`

Comment: Cool. That makes sense. I'm going to add a `setTimeout` as well just in case. UX is not good if this doesn't move the page.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a JS expert, but if you want to perform some action when the user goes back or forward, you could use URL hashes and trigger some function using the jQuery onhashchange event. This will not give you the position in history, and i'm also not sure about cross-browser compatibility, but it did the job for me so far.

```
$(window).on('load' function(){
    var hash = parent.top.location.hash;
    if(hash == '' || hash == '#' || hash == null){
        //if none, set a hash and reload page
        parent.top.location.hash = '#/some/hash';
        parent.top.location.reload(true);//use true if you dont want to use cached items
    }
});
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    do_something(parent.top.location.hash);
});
function do_something(hash){
    //this function will be executed each time the '#' changes
    console.log('hash changed to '+hash);
}
```